# Get real http port where application is registered when I use dynamically port

Tags: java, quarkus

I'm writing a Quarkus application. I must use a dynamic port (set `quarkus.http.port=0` in `application.properties` file).
This is correct, so when I start my application I see that application runs on a random port (every time is different).

How do I get the correct port where application is running? Because if I read the configuration property `@ConfigProperty(name = "quarkus.http.port")` I obtain "0" and not, for example 5962.

Answer (score 1):

This is documented [here](https://quarkus.io/guides/http-reference#listening-on-a-random-port). In short you should use the `quarkus.http.port` property, but if it is injected it can get the wrong value if the injection happens too early. To get around that you can read the value [programmatically](https://quarkus.io/guides/config#programmatically-access-the-configuration), something like:

```
ConfigProvider.getConfig().getValue("quarkus.http.port", Integer.class);
```